# Для чего здесь нужен nop

Tags: ассемблер, x86, tasm

Зачем в этом учебном коде `nop`? Код меняет строчные буквы на заглавные.

```
DATASG SEGMENT PARA
MYTEXT DB 'Our Native Town',13,10,'$'
DATASG ENDS

STACKSG SEGMENT 'Stack'
      DB 12 DUP(?)
STACKSG ENDS

CODESG SEGMENT PARA 'Code'
BEGIN PROC FAR
ASSUME SS:STACKSG,CS:CODESG,DS:DATASG
      PUSH DS
      SUB AX,AX
      PUSH AX
      MOV AX,DATASG
      MOV DS,AX
      LEA BX,MYTEXT
      MOV CX,10H
MT1:  MOV AH,[BX]
      CMP AH,61H
      JB MT2
      CMP AH,7AH
      JA MT2
      CALL COR
MT2:  INC BX
      LOOP MT1
      LEA DX,MYTEXT
      MOV AH,09H
      INT 21H
      RET
BEGIN ENDP
COR   PROC NEAR
      NOP
      AND AH,0DFH
      MOV [BX],AH
      RET
COR   ENDP
CODESG ENDS
END BEGIN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько причин вставлять в код NOP. Одна из них - подогнать размер программы под нужный, чтобы, скажем, она занимала определённый объём памяти. Вторая - выравнивание адресов команд, которые выполняются (для оптимизации). Наиболее же частая причина - улучшить работу конвейера. Чтобы обеспечить правильные безусловные переходы, и чтобы предсказатель ветвлений меньше тупил, вставляется nop, на случай, когда предсказатель ошибается. В случае ошибки он ничего не сделает. При ручном кодировании на ассемблере нет смысла этим заниматься. Это если кратко, потому как получить более развёрнутый ответ можно, если хорошо понимаете архитектуру процессора. Ещё nop часто используется для отладки. В Вашем коде он не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить что:

1. Это место где можно в уже работающей программе поставить инструкцию "точка останова" или "переход в отладчик".
2. Место где можно поставить RET чтобы сделать из процедуры заглушку.

Answer (score 0):

NOP - это инструкция "не операция" т.е ничего не делает.
Формально не нужен.